# How can i use serialization to load more than one instance of an Object from a txt.datei

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

Hello so this is my first question here,

I have created an object called Person and the SubObjekts Professor and Student.

Now I'm trying to save all the instances that I created from them in a .txt file and then loading them again.
So I succeed  with the saving, I created a static ArrayList in Person and every time someone is created they go in this list through the constructor. After that I just saved the List in the .txt file.

Now the Problem is how can I load this List again and use the instances.

```
public static void save() {
        
        try {
        File datei = new File("C:\\Users\\...");
        datei.createNewFile();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(datei));
        
        oos.writeObject(Person.PersonListe);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Die datei wurde gesichert");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Die datei wurde nicht gesichert");
        }
    }
```

When i first tried to save One Objekt and then loading it again i tried something like this but it didnt work.

```
public static void load() {
        
        try {
            File datei = new File("C:\\Users.....");
            
            
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(datei));
            Object rawObject = ois.readObject();
            
            if(rawObject instanceof Person) {
                
            Person P1 = (Person)rawObject;
            System.out.println(P1.vorname + " " + P1.nachname);
            ois.close();
            
            System.out.println("Inhalt wurde geladen");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Kein Inhalt gefunden");
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    }
```

What is left to say its a class projekt and i have no experience with MYSQL and Databases so i didnt use them.

Comment: Serialization uses a binary format so you should not use a `.txt` suffix. Further, you should use `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead of a hardcoded path. You could also use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` when you want to use the current directory but that could also be achieved by simply use a relative path. Also worth reading: [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)…

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a problem description. The `createNewFile()` line is redundand and wasteful. It forces deletion of any existing file and then creation of a new file, then when the OS gets the native part of `new FileOutputStream(...)` it has to do exactly the same things all over again. Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to serialize all the objects inside an `ArrayList`.
Then you can simply serialize the entire list, as `ArrayList` implements `Serializable` by default.

Comment: Yeah, but I also want to load the data again that was saved in the text file so that I can for example change the name.

Comment: Okay I found my answer, i did approach it in the wrong way. Like i saved it in an array and wanted it to load with references but i just needed to load the data in an array. What a dumb mistake 

Comment: Happy you solved it anyways. I would advise you to serialize the entire ```ArrayList``` anyway, as it should be simpler than serializing every single element of the list itself.